# Source for Rav Avraham Yosef's ruling on Ba'alei Teshuva

Tags: eretz-yisrael, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, mesorah-tradition, baal-teshuva

A friend mentioned, and I read the same [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/baal-teshuva-minhag), that Rav Avraham Yosef and/or Rav Ovadiah Yosef ruled that Ba'alei Teshuva in Israel (with no direct masoret of their own) should adopt the Sepharadi masoret.

Can someone help me find a source for this?

Comment: I seem to recall that the reasoning for adopting Sepharadi practices was that R' Yosef Karo is considered Maran of all Jews in Israel and his rulings are binding. However, some common contemporary Sepharadi positions (including rulings by R' Ovadiah Yosef IIRC) do not accord with the Shulchan Aruch, so this has been a point of confusion for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was HaRav Avraham Yosef.  It was initially posted on his website in the [Ask the Rav section.](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/shut2.asp?id=101945)  It caused quite the stir and wound up being carried by the [YNet news organization.](http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-3965332,00.html)  From there it spread to other news outlets.

Comment: Also see [this blog post](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2012/03/answers-to-quiz-questions-and-other.html) by Marc Shapiro, in section 3.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does he hold that Moroccan Baalei tshuva who live in France or Germany have to become Ashkenazim?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, I too am curious about the question you raised, but perhaps it should be asked separately.

Comment: Please be aware that the author of this answer, "Michael Tzadok," has recently been [outed as a Christian missionary](https://www.northjersey.com/story/news/new-jersey/2021/05/03/orthodox-rabbi-nj-accused-double-life-missionary-israel/4868837001/). His real name is Michael Elk. Please also see [here](https://youtu.be/8N6sPqFBt3A) and [here](https://youtu.be/8g71VZrjCpg).