# List of establishing rabbis for each set of minhagim

Tags: minhag, rabbis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, baal-teshuva

I am a baal teshuva who is becoming orthodox and wondering what customs to hold. Is there a list of important rabbis who set minhagim (ie ashkenazi, sephardi yekki, chabad, notable subgroups, etc) and some sources to learn about each? Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) J and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works? Please don't get discouraged for having your first question closed, it is just that this site doesn't work well for personal questions. For these it is better to ask a rav who knows you well and can customize his questions to your context. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: related: [Baal Teshuva Minhag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6741/11501)

Comment: You might also want to take a look at our other questions tagged [baal-tshuva](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baal-teshuva)

Comment: Minhagim are not set by rabbis, they have evolved over time and are codified in some books, e.g., the Shulchan Aruch codifies minhagim from Sefaradim, the Rema will explain where Ashkenazi minhagim differ, the Shulchan Aruch HaRav will do this for Chabad, etc. But to help you decide the customs to hold, a rav is really crucial